# Невозможно редактировать вопрос после первого одобрения чужой правки

Tags: дефект

Нашёл баг редактирования вопросов:

1. Открываем вопрос.
2. Другой юзер с маленькой репой предлагает правку.
3. Одобряем правку
4. Видим сообщение, что нужен ещё один голос для принятия правки
5. Теперь нельзя редактировать метки и вносить правки в вопрос - редактирование быстрое меток не появляется, а на нажатие "править" появляется сообщение из п.4

Comment: При этом, если правку "принять и редактировать" сразу, то подобной проблемы не возникнет.

Comment: @alexolut, про принять и улучшить уже было тут обсуждение

Comment: @Grundy и к чему пришли?

Comment: @alexolut, похоже [вот этот вопрос](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3235/%D0%9D%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%94%D1%83%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8/3237#3237)

Comment: Мне кажется такие проблемы надо сразу на enSO (или даже SE) озвучивать, если есть возможность. Так как проблема в движке и не связана непосредственно с ruSO. Т.е. отсюда она будет дольше идти до тех, кто может с ней реально что-то поделать. Поправьте, если я заблуждаюсь.

Comment: @Grundy хе, мой вопросик :) поясняет ситуацию с Духом, но не поясняет отсутствие обходного пути по текущей проблеме.

Comment: @alexolut, действительно :-) в любом случае, я думаю будет [tag:статус-так-задумано]

Comment: @Grundy иногда хочется "статус-так-задумано" назвать "статус-сразу-всё-не-продумаешь" :)